# Method to output object details taken from main class

Tags: java, class, object, methods

i have a created a main Pet class which contains the pet name and age and 2 sub classes for a Cat and dog which contain the breed, i am trying to create a method to display the information as a string but i am not sure how to pass the arguments to the method. When trying to use the speak method it says expected 3 arguments but received 0.

```
public class Pet {
private String name;
private int age;

public Pet() {
    name = "";
    age = 0;
}

public Pet(String petName, int petAge) {
    name = petName;
    age = petAge;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setName(String petName) {
    name = petName;
}

public void setAge(int petAge) {
    age = petAge;
}

public String toString() {
    return "";
}
```

}

```
public class Cat extends Pet {
private String breed;

public Cat() {
    super();
    breed = "";
}

public Cat(String petName, int petAge, String catBreed) {
    super(petName, petAge);
    breed = catBreed;
}

public String getBreed() {
    return breed;
}

public void setBreed(String catBreed) {
    breed = catBreed;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Pet breed = " + breed;
}

static void speak(String petName, int petAge, String breed) {
    String str = "Miaow! i am " + petName + " a " + petAge + " year old " + breed;
}
```

}

```
public class PetTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cat cat1 = new Cat("Pixel", 4, "tabby");
    Dog dog1 = new Dog("Rex", 9, "terrier");
    System.out.println(cat1.speak());
    System.out.println(dog1.speak());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to speak doesn't match your method signature.

The way your Cat class is written, you'd have to pass petName, petAge, and breed to your speak method, like this:

```
System.out.println(cat1.speak(cat1.getName(), cat1.getAge(), cat1.getBreed()));
```

That's probably not what you meant to do.  Obviously, you want to populate these with the values you used to instantiate your class.  To do that, your method signature for speak() should take no parameters, and instead use the values from the fields you defined in the class.  On top of that, even if your method worked, it doesn't actually return anything.  From the usage, it looks like you want your speak method to return the appropriate string so that it can be printed with System.out.println().

```
public String speak() {
   return "Miaow! i am " + name + " a " + age + " year old " + breed;
}
```

To make it more clear, you can reference the fields of the class using the *this* operator, and use String.format to handle your string interpolation.

```
public String speak() {
   return String.format("Miaow! i am %s a %d year old %s", this.name, this.age, this.breed);
}
```

Welcome to Java!

Comment: Thank you Eric, this seems to work however my classes are in seperate files and name, age and breed and i am getting the error non static field cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Right, missed that.  There are some other problems here, too, but let's start with the one you pointed out.  Static methods are class-specific methods and not object-specific methods.  When you call your constructor to instantiate a Cat object, you're creating an instance of your Cat class, and the name, age and breed are properties of that instance.  So your speak() method should not be static.  And while we're at it, if you want to be able to call it from outside your package, it should also be public.

Comment: An example of a static method might be if you wanted all cats to simply say "Meow".  Because the method operates the same every time, without any reference to the instance, that could be a good place to use the static modifier.

Comment: Also, this looks like it's meant to be an exercise in polymorphism, where you have a class that delegates some stuff to its subclasses.  If that's true, and you want all pets to have a speak() method but with each type of pet to return a type-specific response, you'd want to declare your Pet class as abstract, and give it an abstract speak method.  Then your subclasses (Dog & Cat) would override the speak method to make it say dog or cat things.

Comment: I highly recommend this book to help you with these concepts. https://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Object-Oriented-Analysis-Design/dp/0596008678

Comment: Thats exactly it! it was a polymorphism exercise. thank you for all the tips! managed to make it so that my sub-classes override the speak method from the super-class and now im able to call the method cat1.speak() and it comes out as a customized message. thank you for your help and recommendation will try and get a hold of the book